# Carregar dados do excel na tela

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-excel

Estou com um problemas em carregar os dados de uma planilha na tela (table).

O sistema é feito em C# MVC5 com razor e entity framework, necessito que o usuário escolha um arquivo excel já preenchido e com os dados desse arquivo eu tenho que apresentar em uma tabela html mesmo (table), após isso o usuário irá verificar os dados carregados, supondo que ele verificou os dados e estão em ordem, o mesmo dará um click em um button para fazer o insert na base de dados.

Ou seja, terei que ler linha a linha desa table para fazer o insert.

Até agora só consegui fazer salvar a planilha em um diretório.

Alguém como fazer isso no MVC?

Comment: Jovem, não é bem assim que o site funciona. Que tipo de ajuda você precisa? O que já tentou? Como podemos te ajudar (especificamente falando).

Comment: A sua dificuldade específica está em abrir o arquivo Excel e extrair suas informações? Caso seja isso, adicione essa informação à pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Se você precisa extrair as informações de um Excel sugiro dar uma olhada na biblioteca https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/ . Ela possui manipulações para o Excel,tanto para extrair dados como para gerar.

Se quiser gerar : https://github.com/TBertuzzi/EppPlus

Se quiser ler :

```
   byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes("Caminho do seu arquivo Arquivo");
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file);
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
    {
        //Obtendo a Planilha
        var workBook = package.Workbook;
        if (workBook != null)
        {
            //Verifica se Existe alguma Planilha
            if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
            {
                // Se Existe pega a primeira
                var currentWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();

                //Leitura das Linhas
                for (int j = currentWorksheet.Dimension.Start.Row + 1;
                            j <= currentWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                            j++)
                {
                    orcamento = new OrcamentoBO();
                    orcamento.Linha = j.ToString();
                    //Leitura das Colunas/Celulas
                    for (int i = currentWorksheet.Dimension.Start.Column; i <= currentWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column; i++)
                    {
                        var celula = currentWorksheet.Cells[j, i].Value;

                        if (celula != null)
                        {
                           //sua logica aqui
                        }


                    }


                }

            }
        }
    }
```